# No puedo enviar datos de un fragment a otro... Cómo podría hacerlo?

Tags: java, android

He probado con algunos bundle e intents... Algo como esto, pero no funciona. Quiero enviar datos desde un fragment a otro, ambos se encuentran en la misma activity, pero los datos que quiero enviar los obtengo en un fragment y necesito recibirlos en cualquier otro fragment.

Con esto envío los datos

```
Bundle args = new Bundle(); 
args.putString("email", email);
fragment.setArguments(args);
```

Con esto recibo los datos

```
String EMAIL = getArguments().getString("email");
```

Cuál podría ser la solución? Alguna idea de cómo enviar datos desde fragment a fragment.
Desde ya, muchas gracias por su tiempo!

Comment: Parece que son dos preguntas en una... y también la pregunta no es del todo clara. ¿Son dos `Fragment` en la misma `Activity` o en distintas `Activity`s? ¿Cómo recuperas los datos en el `Fragment`?, puedes [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/167677/edit) para mostrarlo. Tampoco indicas la situación actual del código: ¿da error, qué error... simplemente no funciona, la app se detiene, etc?

Comment: @A.Cedano acabo de editar la pregunta. Saludos amigo y muchas gracias.

Comment: @MatíasNicolásNúñezRivas como lo realizas es correcto, tal vez tienes un problema a la hora de realizar la transacción, ¿como lo estas realizando agrega esa parte?

Comment: @Jorgesys No he implementado nada aparte de el código de arriba como para realizar la transacción... Cómo es eso?

Comment: @Jorgesys intente colocar un begin.transaction pero me aparecia en rojo cuando lo implementé en el fragment, por eso al final sólo dejé el código de arriba.

Comment: Ya lo solucione poniendo un código de transacción. Muchas gracias por su ayuda chicos.

Comment: @MatíasNicolásNúñezRivas **bueno si no estas realizando una transacción es imposible enviar los datos del bundle =P** se supone que al realizar la transacción es cuando se envían los datos, saludos.